How much space do I have for the file system?
I need to know how much space I have.
There are two 2TB hard drives. The first has three partitions. The third partition seems to be the filesystem partition and it has 2TB available. In Settings > About, it tells me I have 31.0 GiB, and a disk capacity of 4.1 TB.
I wouldn’t think that programming uses a huge amount of hard disk on the Linux computer. If I have 2 TB of, I wouldn’t expect to run out. What I want to do is have most of one drive for the filesystem. I would be happy to have the second drive ether serve as additional space for the filesystem, or space for me to store documents, images, etc. In one article I read, it suggested the second drive should have a mount point at /home. That would be fine.
Here are my questions:
How much space does the filesystem have available, and if only 31 GB, do I need to expand that partition to make more space available?
What is the Microsoft Reserved partition ? Should I leave it ?
Is the second drive a single partition ? Is it formatted ? How should I format it, what filesystem ?
What follows is all the information I have gathered from Settings>About, from Disks, and from typing df -h into terminal.
Dell Precision 3460
Memory      31.0 GiB
Processor       12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700 × 20
Graphics        NV167 / Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL-S GT1)
Disk Capacity       4.1 TB
OS Name     Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
OS Type     64-bit
Gnome Version   3.36.8
Windowing System    X11

Drive 1
Model           PC801 NVMe SK hynix 2TB (51003141)
Size            2.0 TB (2,048,408,248,320 bytes)
Partitioning        GUID Partition Table
Serial Number       SJBAN43821400A65F


    Partition 1     ESP Partition 1  996 MB FAT
    Size            996 MB — 875 MB free (12.1% full)
    Device          /dev/nvme0n1p1
    UUID            F22C-2D58
    Partition Type      EFI System
    Contents        FAT (32-bit version) — Mounted at /boot/efi

    Partition 2     OS Partition 2  8.6 GB FAT
    Size            8.6 GB (8,589,934,592 bytes)
    Device          /dev/nvme0n1p2
    UUID            E844-683F
    Partition Type      Microsoft Reserved
    Contents        FAT (32-bit version) — Not Mounted


    Partition 3     Filesystem Partition 3  2.0 TB Ext4
    Size            2.0 TB — 2.0 TB free (2.0% full)
    Device          /dev/nvme0n1p3
    UUID            48752f58-52ee-4666-ae9f-3a1903063253
    Partition Type      Linux Filesystem
    Contents        Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root


Drive 2     2.0 TB Unknown
Model           PC801 NVMe SK hynix 2TB (51003141)
Size            2.0 TB (2,048,408,248,320 bytes)
Partitioning        
Serial Number        SJBAN43821400A65H

    Size        2.0 TB (2,048,408,248,320 bytes)
    Device      /dev/nvme1n1
    Contents    Unknown


$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted                       on
udev            16G   0     16G    0%    /dev    
tmpfs           3.2G  2.5M  3.2G   1%    /run    
/dev/nvme0n1p3  1.9T  8.4G  1.8T   1%    /       
tmpfs           16G   0     16G    0%    /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1%    /run/lock
tmpfs           16G   0     16G    0%    /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K  0      100%  /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop1      64M   64M   0      100%  /snap/core20/1828
/dev/loop2      50M   50M   0      100%  /snap/snapd/18357
/dev/loop4      347M  347M  0      100%  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop3      46M   46M   0      100%  /snap/snap-store/638
/dev/loop5      92M   92M   0      100%  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/nvme0n1p1  946M  112M  835M   12%   /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G  116K  3.2G   1%    /run/user/1000
/dev/loop6      39M   39M   0      100%  /snap/snapd/21759
/dev/loop7      64M   64M   0      100%  /snap/core20/2318
/dev/loop8      350M  350M  0      100%  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143


Pls run df -h in your Ubuntu terminal and edit your question with the results.

Pls edit your question and remove the comments.

It wouldn't let me put it all into one comment, and it took out the line feeds. You want me to remove the comment that asks for more drive information ?

yes, delete your comments and edit your question instead and add the results there. You have Edit under your question.

@Crash as amar said, edit your question with the additional information that we ask for, and don't add them to comments.  Your reputation might be too low for the edit to get immediately posted and will have to go through an approval process.  Just let us know here here that you have edited your question, and we can approve the edits.

From what I see /dev/nvme0n1p3 1.9T 8.4G 1.8T 1% / is your system partition

It seems to have fixed the readability of the information I added as a comment. Now it is readable. Before it had removed the line feeds so it was very hard to read. Do I still need to edit my question to add my reply to it, rather than having the reply be a comment ? I have no idea why it added blue boxes to some of the original question.

It didn't hurt readability, except that the blue box, now a gray box, stops for three lines. I don't know if I can edit this and remove the boxes, or connect them. I see there is still a copy of the reply with the linefeeds still missing, which should be removed. I don't see edit buttons for the stuff that needs to be removed. I think everything below the edit button needs to be removed.

You may also want to think about upgrading see this https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

and pls read this if you are going to ask more questions later, https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

"In Settings > About, it tells me I have 31.0 GiB"... That's 31 GB of RAM, aka memory

I have edited the question. I do not know how to take out the boxes, or to make them continuous where they currently stop for three lines.

Hi, I think I have just about got it all working. It has not been easy. First, I added a partition table. That made the partition become "Unallocated space". As unallocated space, I could not do anything with it, all options were grayed out. I read about unallocated space, but nothing seemed to help. Finally, I re-partitioned, formatted and added the partition table, a couple of times. Finally it looked right. It was no longer unallocated, and it became red, like a usable partition.

Continuing from last comment: So I set the mount point at /home, and set it to mount automatically at startup. I re-booted. Now after accepting my password, it kept asking for it again and again. I booted into the flash drive and reset the mount point to its default. I re-booted and again was in the password loop. I used the flash again and unmounted the second drive. I was still in the password loop. I re-installed Ubnuntu and this time with the second drive already prepared, the second hard drive was automatically mounted.

Continuing from last two comments: Now I see drive two in Other Locations. When I select it it says Folder is Empty. So I tried to copy a folder with pictures I use for the screen background, to the second hard drive. I get Error while copying. The folder cannot be copied because you do not have permission to create it in the destination. I tried to create a folder in the new drive by right clicking. But the New Folder option is gray, unavailable. The New Folder option in the drop down menu from the Drive2 thing in the upper left of the folder view, is also gray and unavailable.

Continuing from last 3 comments: I right clicked in the directory area and selected properties (for the second drive). Under permissions, all three boxes are grayed out, and it tells me You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions. I looked this up on the internet and found that I need to use the chmod command. However, everything here is about not being able to access a file, not about accessing the hard drive. I don't know how to use chmod so it fixes the drive, or the partition.

Continuing from the last four comments because there just isn't enough space available in a comment: I have given up on the idea of mounting the second drive at /home. I will be happy just to be able to use the second drive at all. My guess is that the second drive needs to be set up before installing Ubuntu on the first hard drive. That must be why I got into the endless password loop. There were already folders in /home, so it was too late to set the second drive to /home.
Please tell me how to gain access to the second hard drive.

Here is what I now get with the df -h command:

How much space do I have?
The command df abbreviation for disk free shows your partitions. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_(Unix), You may also run df --help to get all of the switches and their functions.
The system partition is the disk partition that contains the operating system folder, known as the system root. By default, in Linux, operating system files are mounted at / (the root directory). Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_partition_and_boot_partition
So in your case:
Filesystem      Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted                       on
udev            16G   0     16G    0%    /dev    
tmpfs           3.2G  2.5M  3.2G   1%    /run    
/dev/nvme0n1p3  1.9T  8.4G  1.8T   1%    /      

It means you have 1.8T available in that partition.

So I have 1.8TB space for the filesystem ? That should be enough. How about the second drive. Is it partitioned, formatted, do I need to set its mounting point ?

Pls. read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask, https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask and this https://askubuntu.com/help/no-one-answers They are from help files down at the bottom of the screen, this site is for a lot of people and to make it less confusing the answers are only to one question at a time. You may ask other questions by filing a new question.
